# DL160 G5 fails to boot CentOS 5.11

Tags: centos5, boot, gpt, mbr, hp-proliant

I'm trying to install CentOS 5.11 on DL160 G5, with 4 bays holding 3TB sized drives.

The installation with default partition layout completes successfully, however on boot I get to a blinking cursor screen - it's not even reaching GRUB.

I've tried updating BIOS to latest one available (17/11/2011), and even manually sizing the boot partition to 200 MB - it's still has the same effect.

I presume a GPT needs to be used (rather than the default MBR), however unable to find how to enable it during the installation.

Comment: Which RAID controller is installed?

Comment: There is no raid controller, I tried both with default partition layout and with MDRAID 1 over boot and root partitions.